# cocos2dx v3.10 game Application is getting dead in android (can't load native library)

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

i have developed game in cocos2dx v3.10 and want to deploy it into android platform i have prefer to use android studio for it.

first i have compile project using below command

$cocos compile -p android --android-studio

when i load project in android studio and run it the game is getting crash directly and fire following errors in log cat.

my java code is

```
protected void onLoadNativeLibraries() {
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            Bundle bundle = ai.metaData;
            String libName = bundle.getString("android.app.lib_name");
            System.loadLibrary(libName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And Log cat is displaying this errors

```
04-07 13:05:30.112 17236-17236/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-07 13:05:30.220 17236-17236/? D/JniHelper: JniHelper::setJavaVM(0xb770bb20), pthread_self() = -1225532620
04-07 13:05:30.220 17236-17236/? D/main: cocos_android_app_init
04-07 13:05:30.220 17236-17236/? D/cocos2d: android build version:23
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jmethodID was NULL
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     in call to CallObjectMethodV
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x742042a0 self=0xb770dc60
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | sysTid=17236 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f3db34
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | state=R schedstat=( 53423960 14681877 62 ) utm=2 stm=3 core=3 HZ=100
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | stack=0xbe402000-0xbe404000 stackSize=8MB
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #00 pc 0035c6d5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+116)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #01 pc 0033d7cf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+138)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #02 pc 0024f6a1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+760)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #03 pc 0024fd3f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+54)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #04 pc 000fc0b3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+30)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #05 pc 00101bb5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::JniValueType*) (.constprop.95)+8164)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #06 pc 0010f043  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+498)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #07 pc 001105e9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallObjectMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+28)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #08 pc 003a1dd8  /data/app/com.demo.test1-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_JNIEnv::CallObjectMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+92)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #09 pc 003a1f58  /data/app/com.demo.test1-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (_getClassID(char const*)+108)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #10 pc 003a24f0  /data/app/com.demo.test1-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(cocos2d::JniMethodInfo_&, char const*, char const*, char const*)+136)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #11 pc 0039f194  /data/app/com.demo.test1-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (getPackageNameJNI()+132)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #12 pc 0050d578  /data/app/com.demo.test1-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::UserDefault::initXMLFilePath()+72)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #13 pc 0050d464  /data/app/com.demo.test1-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::UserDefault::getInstance()+36)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #14 pc 00395d88  /data/app/com.demo.test1-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (AppDelegate::AppDelegate()+76)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #15 pc 00395a5c  /data/app/com.demo.test1-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos_android_app_init(_JNIEnv*)+64)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #16 pc 0039d7e4  /data/app/com.demo.test1-1/lib/arm/libcocos2dcpp.so (JNI_OnLoad+40)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #17 pc 0025026b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, _jobject*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+1174)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #18 pc 002c2397  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime_nativeLoad(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+178)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #19 pc 0021bb8d  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Runtime_nativeLoad__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_ClassLoader_2Ljava_lang_String_2+144)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native method)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:435)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   - locked <0x05e716ad> (a java.lang.Runtime)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:248)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:263)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java:-1)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-07 13:05:30.303 17236-17236/? A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]
```

My android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d/cocos)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

PROJECT_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \

PROJECT_FILES += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes/*.cpp)

PROJECT_FILES := $(PROJECT_FILES:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(PROJECT_FILES)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes

# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_END


LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static

# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_END

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,.)

# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_END
```

Comment: When I had this issue, it was because the paths in android.mk was incorrect.

Comment: i have edit my question i have put my android.mk file code please examine it and tell me if there is any modification needed.

Comment: Can you show us your manifest file?

Comment: Btw what a ndk version are you using? It needs to be v10. v11 is not supported in cocos2dx yet

Comment: Any new information on this issue? I'm in exact same issue now. Just want to know if you have fixed this problem